# Must one pay for the esrog and arovos before succot

Tags: halacha, transactions, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

Must one pay for an esrog or arovot before succot. Most likely every retailer will tell you if you dont pay you are not yotsai. The question really is has he paid his wholesaler and has the wholesaler paid the farmer or grower something very unlikely before yom tov and before he has sold them. So is one yotsai.

Comment: And if so, does it have to be cash or can it be a credit card or cheque (delayed payment)?

Comment: I think most botai din accept that giving a cheque although it has not been cashed is considered 'paid' and therefore the seller is the 'muchzak'. This could be a different question.

Comment: there is a talk of the lubavitcher rebbe about this... i will tell u if i find it.

Comment: Isn't personalty acquired by lifting? Why would payment be relevant (as long as there's _daas makne_ from a promise to pay)?

Answer (score 3):

[Sefer Haminhagim (Chabad)](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/56.htm#t539) writes that "One does not necessarily have to pay for the Four Species before Sukkos".

They cite:

> "See the Acharonim on Shulchan Aruch, [Orach Chayim 658](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3038); Sdei Chemed, Aseifas Dinim: Daled Minim 3:2; ibid., Klalim, Lamed 141:24."

---

Per [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30510&pgnum=285): When the Lubavitcher Rebbe came to the previous Lubavitcher Rebbe and suggested he pay the Arba Minim seller before Sukkos, the previous Lubavitcher Rebbe asked "Is he in need of money for Sukkos?" The Rebbe understood that the previous Lubavitcher Rebbe would specifically *not* pay before Yom Tov; however, he himself would always pay right away for his Arba Minim.

Answer (score 1):

See Sefer Nitei Gavriel perek 46:1,20 which discusses this with many sources.In short there might be a problem of a kinyan min haTorah which is absent without payment.There is a Rabbinic kinyan of mishicha,but we want lachem for the mitzvah. It is best to be fully paid before Yom tov.

A check is like money ,but a post dated check is not so clear,some retailers feel happy with it while other not,every situation is different,if he knows you or not,see Shevet Halevi 7:83.